# Query Sql para provisionar os saldos bancarios

Tags: sql

Boa tarde, preciso montar uma query que calcule pra mim numa coluna a parte o saldo atual deduzindo o valor a pagar e somando o valor a receber, ficando assim:
saldo_residual = (receber - pagar + saldobancário)
Tenho tres tabelas origens, tabela SE8010 é saldos bancários, campo E8_SALATUA é saldo atual, campo E8_DTSALAT é data
tabela SE1010 é contas receber, campo  E1_VENCREA é data vencimento receber, E1_SALDO é saldo atual 
tabela SE2010 é contas pagar, campo E2_SALDO é o valor pagar do dia, campo E2_VENCREA data vencimento pagar.

Estou usando a seguinte consulta.

```
DECLARE @filial CHAR (2);
SET @filial = ('01');
SELECT E8_FILIAL = @filial, SUM(ISNULL(E8_SALATUA,0)) AS VALOR,  E8_DTSALAT,  SUM(E2_SALDO) AS PAGAR, SUM(E1_SALDO) AS RECEBER, (SUM(ISNULL(E8_SALATUA,0)) - SUM(ISNULL(E2_SALDO,0)) + SUM(ISNULL(E1_VALOR,0))) AS SALDO_ATUAL
FROM  SE8010 
LEFT JOIN SE1010 ON      
E1_VENCREA = E8_DTSALAT  AND     
(CAST(E1_FILIAL AS CHAR (2))) = E8_FILIAL 
LEFT JOIN SE2010 ON      
E2_VENCREA = E8_DTSALAT AND      
E2_VENCREA = E1_VENCREA AND (CAST(E2_FILIAL AS CHAR (2))) = E8_FILIAL
WHERE SE8010.D_E_L_E_T_ = '' 
GROUP BY E8_FILIAL, E8_BANCO, E8_SALATUA, E8_DTSALAT, E8_CONTA, E8_AGENCIA
```

porem o resultado nao é efetivo para as datas provionadas para 7 dias .
Para que  eu possa criar uma coluna com uma variável para guardar o saldo (residual do dia anterior - pagar dia seguinte - receber dia seguinte ) como poderia ajustar esta querie para que ele me provisione valores para data maiores que hoje? Alguem pode me ajudar?

Comment: Me parecem ser tabelas do Totvs Protheus , publique a estrutura das tabelas , o sgbd em questão , já viu se o erp não tem um rel padrão para isto ?

Comment: tem um relatório padrão sim, porém temos que criar um dentro do Analytics - GoodData.

Comment: Quando fiz um evento do GD a Totvs vendia o peixe que tinha estes extratores... Pense então em um extrator com uma tabela temporária e uma procedure para povoar , creio que será mais fácil usando a E8 como base , um job poderia povoarvesta tabela e o extrator vai nela.